# Term for manipulating zero, one or more items as a single object

Tags: terminology

Let's say we have a tree structure, DOM for instance, and we wish to make a function for finding all nodes meeting certain criteria and returning them in some way.

The naive way to do this is to return an array, list or similar of found nodes. However, doing so requires the use of loops or higher-order functions (such as `map`) to process all entries.

jQuery and some other DOM traversal frameworks I've seen partially abstracts the individual nodes away, instead working with specialized sets that can contain any number of nodes (or none at all). These objects have all the methods you'd expect the nodes to have, except it applies the calls to all the nodes in the set (where applicable), ignoring the call if the set is empty.

As an example, jQuery allows you to use `$('img').css('opacity', 0.5)` to find all images on a page and make them all partially transparent. The traversal of the matched nodes and application of the call to the individual images happens behind the scenes.

Is there a term for this way of ignoring the plurality of elements and operating on zero, one or more as if they were a single object? More specifically, do these objects themselves have a name?